# Laurent series of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+p^2}$, $ p>0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

I need help finding the main part of the laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+p^2}$ in $ip,-ip$ since these are the two poles of $f$. Due to the orders of the poles are 1 I just have to find $a_{-1}(z-ip)^{-1}$ and $b_{-1}(z+ip)^{-1}$.

I want to use $2ipf(z)=\frac{e^{(z-ip)i-p}}{z-ip}-\frac{e^{(z-ip)i-p}}{z+ip}$ since this is a given hint.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(z)=f_1(z)-f_2(z):=\frac{e^{(z-ip)i-p}}{2ip(z-ip)}-\frac{e^{(z-ip)i-p}}{2ip(z+ip)}$$

Since
$$e^{iy}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{i^k y^k}{k!}$$

We have
$$\frac{e^{iy}}{y}=\frac{1}{y}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{i^{j+1} y^j}{(j+1)!}$$

$$f_1 (z)=\frac{e^{-p}}{2ip}\left(\frac{1}{(z-ip)}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{i^{j+1}(z-ip)^{j}}{(j+1)!}\right):=\sum_{k=-1}^\infty B_k (z-ip)^k$$

$$B_{-1}=\frac{e^{-p}}{2ip}, B_j=\frac{e^{-p}}{2ip}\frac{i^{j+1}}{(j+1)!}(j\ge 0)$$

$$(z+ip)^{-1}=(z-ip+2ip)^{-1}=(2ip)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{z-ip}{2ip}\right)^{-1}=(2ip)^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \left(\frac{z-ip}{2ip}\right)^k$$

Therefore:
$$e^{(z-ip)i}(z+ip)^{-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{i^j (z-ip)^j}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(z-ip)^k}{(2ip)^k}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^l \frac{i^{l} }{(2p)^{k}(l-k)!} (z-ip)^l:=\sum_{l=0}^\infty C_l (z-ip)^l$$

And $C_{-1}=0$.

$$f_2(z):=\frac{e^{(z-ip)i-p}}{2ip(z+ip)}=\frac{e^{-p}}{2ip}\frac{e^{(z-ip)i}}{(z+ip)}=\frac{e^{-p}}{2ip}\sum_{l=0}^\infty C_l (z-ip)^l$$.

Thus we obtained the Laurent series for $f(z)$ near $z=ip$.

$$f(z)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l (z-ip)^l, a_l=B_l+B_{-1}C_l$$
$$a_{-1}=B_{-1}=\frac{e^{-p}}{2ip}$$

Similarly we can obtain:
$$f(z)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_l (z+ip)^l$$
$$b_{-1}=-\frac{e^{p}}{2ip}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see how to solve the task based on this. I need to find $a_{-1}$ and $b_{-1}$ with $f(z)=\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} a_n (z-ip)^n$ and $f(z)=\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} b_n (z+ip)^n$. I understand what you wrote down, but not how we now can construct the solution now.

Comment: Now I understood what you want. I modified the answer and you can read off coefficients $a_n$ from the answer.